# Adobe Livecycle -- Is there a way to use the same binding more than once?

Tags: data-binding, pdf, binding, adobe, livecycle

Version: 8.2.1.5161.566259

It seems that attempting to bind the same item from my Data View to more than one field...

For example, I have a collection of objects named "Customers". I have one part of my PDF list customer names and another list their addresses. However, the addresses never show up because the Customers array is already bound somewhere else.

A hierarchy view:

```
- Page
  - Customer Names (subform) - $record.Customers.Customer[*]
    Customer.Name - $.FullName
  + Other Section (subform)
  - Customer Addresses (subform) - $record.Customers.Customer[*]
    Address 1 - $.Address1
    Address 2 - $.Address2
    City - $.City
    State - $.State
    ZipCode - $.ZipCode
```

The problem is that the Customer Addresses subform doesn't actually get bound. Any way to fix this that is simple. I know in WPF and Silverlight you can bind to the same data property multiple times, so I figured it was similar with Adobe LiveCycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately multiple data-binding doesn't work on repeated element nodes ...
The only workaround I know is to fill one of the two section programatically using JavaScript.